# fetch data by id from one table and show in different defferent pages

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

How can I fetch/select data from one table.

Suppose, I made table with the name "TableA" in the database.And I made two column  for "id" and "post_name".

```
------------------
| id| post_name |
------------------
| 1 | Orange    |
| 2 | Mango     |
```

---

And I have two pages with the name "Page1.php" and "Page2.php".

I want to fetch data from "TableA" by id(row).

I want fetch data of id=1(orange) in Page1.
I want fetch data of id=2(mango) in Page2.

Help me to write the query.

```
<?php
   include("../../configure/config.php");
   $sql56=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from info_detail");
 ?>

<table>
  <?php
  if(mysqli_num_rows($sql56) > 0){
  while($res15 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql56)){         
   ?>
<!------------------------------>
<tr>
<td id="tdtitle_left">Post Name :</td>
<td id="tdtitle_right"><?php echo $res15['post_name'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="tdtitle_left">Post Date :</td>
<td id="tdtitle_right"><?php echo $res15['post_date'];?>  ||  <?php echo $res15['post_time'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="tdtitle_left">Post Update Date :</td>
 <td id="tdtitle_right"><?php echo $res15['post_update_date'];?>  ||  <?php echo 
 $res15['post_update_time'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td id="tdtitle_left">Information : </td>
  <td id="tdtitle_right"><?php echo $res15['information'];?></td>
</tr>
<?php
}
}              
?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

First make two pages. PageA.php and PageB.php
Make the include in both pages

```
<?php
   include("../../configure/config.php");

   On PageA.php
   $sql56=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from info_detail where id = 1");

   On PageB.php
   $sql56=mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * from info_detail where id = 2");
 ?>
```